# PHP Warning: Unknown: Unable to allocate memory for pool

Tags: php, apc

My site is a high traffic one built with LAMP stack. Recently I am getting the below warnings from PHP

```
PHP Warning:  Unknown: Unable to allocate memory for pool. in Unknow
n on line 0, referer:<<URL>>
```

Most of my search in Google says that its related to APC memory setting. But my server admin is saying that APC is not running out of memory and its having enough capacity of 2 GB.

```
PHP Version : PHP 5.3.15
APC Version : APC-3.1.10

apc.ttl=7200
apc.shm_size=2024M
```

Now wanted to know what will be the implication of this php warnings to my customers. Can I ignore this warnings or need to take any corrective measures immediately.

Is this related to APC or PHP and how to fix the same.

Thanks in advance

regards

Mano